# Word for "collecting money for a special event from a group of people"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

What is the English word for "collecting money for a special event from a group of people"?

For example, say some friends are planing a party. Each one has to contribute some amount of money to the event. What is the word or phrase that can be used to explain this kind of activity?

I have found "fund raising" to have a similar meaning, but I feel it's more along the lines of "collecting money for some charity event". Is that right, and is there a better word I can use?

Comment: If "each one has to contribute some amount…" is vital then there is no clear equivalent in English.

Was that vital, or would it be sufficient for each to contribute, with neither amount nor proportion specified?

If "each one has to contribute some amount…" meant rather, "each one has to contribute (something)…" then that's a major problem in translation, and it does invite suggestions such as whip-round, kitty or passing the hat.

Either way, can you make clear whether you demand the "word" you Asked for, or a "phrase" or "clause" would be equally suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words whip, whip-round or kitty may work here. The whip or kitty being the account or purse where these group funds are held and from where group purchases are made.

Comment: I'll take whip-round as the answer for my question. Thanks a lot. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+whip-round

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the hat?  This implies an informal request for contributions from a group of people.